# Second Moments of linear SDEs

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider and SDE of the form

$$
dX = AX\cdot dt + BX\cdot dW_t
$$
where $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^2$. How I can calculate the second moments $E[X_1^2]$ and $E[X_2^2]$ of the two variables using Ito's Formula? I want only hints then I can do calculus on myself.

Comment: Have you tried treating this as a multi-dimensional Geometric Brownian motion?

Comment: You mean looking at its exact solution $S_t=S_0\exp{((\mu-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma dW_t)}$

Comment: there's a differential in the exponential that shouldn't be there. Then you can use the moment generating function for a gaussian random variable

Comment: Is $X_k$ an index or the value at $t=k$? In the first case, are these two separate equations for $X_1,X_2$ or are the equations coupled?

Comment: $X_k$ is the index of the variable not the value at a time. They could be separated or coupled, depends on the matrices. In my case they are coupled.

Comment: Yeah, I unconsciously assumed the equations were separated

Comment: @RScrlli I'm looking on wiki and found the exact solution and also the first moment $E[X_t]=X_0\exp{(\mu t)}$ but for the second moment can't find infos